# One to one user can not see each other during agora video call

Tags: agora.io

I have implemented the agora code in my angular 5 application using agora CDN. Camera is opening but one to one user can not see each other's video frame.
Why?

var self = this;
var client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: 'rtc', codec: "h264" });

client.init('my key', function () {

```
console.log("AgoraRTC client initialized");
client.join(null, 'TestChanel', null, function (uid) {

    console.log("User " + uid + " join channel successfully");
    self.uId = uid;

    var localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
        // streamID: uid,
        // audio: true,
        //  video: true,
        //  screen: false,

        streamID: uid,
        audio: true,
        cameraId: self.deviceId,
        // microphoneId: self.microphone,
        video: true,
        screen: false,
        extensionId: 'minllpmhdgpndnkomcoccfekfegnlikg',
    }
    );

    localStream.init(function () {

        console.log("getUserMedia successfully");
        localStream.play('agora_local');
       // localStream.play('video-caller');

        client.publish(localStream, function (err) {

            console.log("Publish local stream error: " + err);
        });

        client.on('stream-published', function (evt) {

            console.log("Publish local stream successfully");
        });


        client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {

            var stream = evt.stream;
            console.log("New stream added: " + stream.getId());

            client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
                console.log("Subscribe stream failed", err);
            });
        });
        client.on('stream-subscribed', function (evt) {

            var remoteStream = evt.stream;
            console.log("Subscribe remote stream successfully: " + remoteStream.getId());
            remoteStream.play('agora_remote' + remoteStream.getId());
        })






    }, function (err) {

        console.log("getUserMedia failed", err);
    });

}, function (err) {

    console.log("Join channel failed", err);
});
```

}, function (err) {

```
console.log("AgoraRTC client init failed", err);
```

});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post code as an image as it makes it difficult for people to easily see your problem and answer the question. Please edit your question to add the code as text. It might also be useful to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you looked at the Agora NPM package for Angular? Here is an article that covers this topic. https://medium.com/@Anderson7301/building-a-video-chat-app-with-agora-and-angular-6-858d72b6fa0d

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that might help you resolve this issue:

1. Take advantage of Typescript typings to help with debugging. You can install a basic typing library for the SDK with the command `npm install --save-dev @types/agora-rtc-sdk`, to give you more debugging power.
2. Set a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or use `rxjs`'s [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) before you try to `play` the remote stream, that sometimes helps ensure the stream is played.
3. Test not assigning a `cameraId` in the `createStream()` method, or using `this` instead of `self` - you could be having issues with Angular because of it.

Also make sure in future tests that the `uid` used in [`join()`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/v2.5.2/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#join) is of the same type for both users. I've experienced this issue before when one client was passing in a `number` and the other was passing in a `string`.

If you're using Chrome to test this between two users, then it's probably not a browser issue, but, depending on the SDK version, there are some [known bugs](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/release_web_video?platform=Web#issues-fixed) you should look into.